# How to get data from installed DB and insert the extracted data in New DB in iOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I have a Database (used SQLite ) file that i copy in the documents while the applicaiotn is installed , now i have added one field in a Table and i want to install new DB in the Device. To achieve this i think i have to do Database Migration.

The issue i am facing is that I am not able to think the Code to get Whole Data from the installed Database and then insert that extracted data into New Database (while installation) , I have less experienced in iOS Programming so please Provide details from Scratch .

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an iOS issue, but a conceptional problem.

If you want to add new tables to the database, why do you copy an old version of the database rather than one that already contains the new tables?

As for the import of existing data, simply read out the old database and write it to the new database. This should be simple enough with the available SQLite API. Explaining the details would be beyond the scope of this question. (You will find enough info on these basic things online.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) 
It will be Great if you suggest some Good link for the aforesaid content .